# Including pending update list in motd

Tags: linux, apt, pam, motd

How would you include the list and / or count of pending updates in the welcome banner?

Eg.

```
username: User
password: *****

Hi 'User', welcome on 'localhost'
There are 8 pending updates, you need to execute "sudo apt-get upgrade"

User@localhost:~$
```

Bonus question : How to display this "extra message" only for users belonging to the "sudo" group ?

Comment: Put code to do that in /etc/profile, and have that code check for group membership.

Comment: Recent versions of Ubuntu already do this, have a look at `/etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available`.

Comment: @mgorven Confirmed. `/etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available` does it via `/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available` on my Ubuntu 11.04 box.

Comment: Just to keep everybody posted, I'm not droping this. currently I've found that you can get 60% of this by using the package `update-notifier-common` but according to this http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=437176 debian team has choosen not to automatically update the motd because of security bugs that affected Ubuntu.